# Opengl Unbind Texture?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

- Eu tenho uma lista de objetos;
- Cada objeto possui diferentes quantidades de textura;
- Quando faço glBindTexture de 2 texturas (difusa e especular) para um objeto, pode acontecer que o próximo objeto possa ter apenas 1 textura (difusa);
- Acontece que a segunda textura do primeiro objeto acaba sendo enviada para o próximo objeto a ser renderizado, pois a segunda textura ainda continua vinculada.

Questão: Gostaria de saber como proceder nesses casos e tentar desvincular todas as texturas anteriores é apropriado? Se sim, como? Pois já tentei usar a função glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); só que não está desvinculando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver a textura especular da parede foi parar no óculos que só possui a textura difusa. (E não, por coincidência parece que o óculos está refletindo o cenário, mas não é isso)

for (Mesh& obj : openglDraw::objs) {

```
...
if (obj.textureDiffuse.size() != 0) {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for (unsigned int &j : obj.textureDiffuse) {
        openglUtils::setTexture(programme, i, j);
        openglUtils::setInt(programme, "material.diffmap", i);
        i++;
    }
    for (unsigned int &j : obj.textureSpecular) {
        openglUtils::setTexture(programme, i, j);
        openglUtils::setInt(programme, "material.specmap", i);
        i++;
    }
    ...
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Três Alternativas que eu encontrei e funcionou:

**Primeira Alternativa: Shaders Diferentes**

*Utilizar um shader diferente para objetos com textura especular e difusa, e outro shader para objetos com somente a textura difusa.*

Talvez é a melhor alternativa caso não exista a necessidade de criar uma cena realista, ou seja, sem a textura especular em alguns objetos. Além de tornar o processamento gráfico mais robusto.

Obs: Nem todos os materiais na vida real possuem o comportamento especular significante.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segunda Alternativa: Utilizar a Textura Difusa como Especular**

*Durante o tempo de vinculação das texturas você pode verificar se o objeto possui alguma textura especular, caso não possuir, vincule as texturas difusas com o nome das texturas especulares.*

Nessa opção você irá simular uma iluminação especular. Não irá resultar em algo realista mas não irá gerar defeitos na iluminação.

Obs: Como na maioria as texturas especulares são obtidas a partir da difusa, é possível converter a imagem difusa em tons de cinza para usar como especular.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Terceira Alternativa: Alterar o objeto**

*Utilizando Blender, Maia, 3Ds Max, ou qualquer outro editor, você pode importar o objeto, adicionar um textura especular (reutilizando o mesmo mapeamento) e exportar o objeto editado*

É a opção mais correta caso queira garantir que todos os objetos tenham textura especular.

Abaixo um exemplo adicionando a textura especular ao objeto usando Blender.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]